# Data Studio: Turn a parameter into a Data Source Filter

Tags: dashboard, looker-studio

So I have a parameter which I have used for some calculations in the report. I also have a  data source filter which uses the same labels. Currently I am using both but want to combine them to reduce steps while filtering.

Data source filter is "Region Distribution"

Parameter is "param_Region"

"param_Region" currently only filters the three calculations named leadGoals, MQLGoals and SQLGoals.

"Region Distribution" filters everything but it messes up the calculation.

They both have same labels so I would like to combine them so just one filter affects the whole dashboard.

Here is the dashboard: https://datastudio.google.com/u/0/reporting/8ee516a9-e93e-4b2f-b782-871d6c6a42f9/page/WdShC/edit

Here is the data source: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Jc3T5S0EqblsEb61-z_7XQuwH0qq2Ccrm0FFv66KqGY/edit#gid=0

Answer (score 0):

To apply filting data by selecting a parameter:

- generate a new field to compare the parameter value with the values of the field:
  [image]

```
param_Region = "all"
OR UPPER(param_Region) = UPPER(Region Distribution)
```

- Add a filter for that new field.
- Apply this filter to any graph.